# 'copy' always leaves a blank line at the end of a file. Why?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

When I use the DOS Copy command to copy multiple files into one file the result always has an extra blank line (cursor return line feed) at the end.  How do I avoid creating this blank line?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using binary mode to see if it gives you the result you need:

```
COPY /B file1 + file2 dest
```

Comment: Wanted to add, I had a similar problem and this worked for me.